# Do all Nehalem-based and later Xeon processors have an integrated Memory Controller (IMC)?

Tags: x86, cpu, intel

The [Xeon page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon) says that Nehalem-based Xeon processors have an Integrated Memory Controller (IMC).

*Volume 1: Basic Architecture* listed on [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) page also says in section 2.2.5: "Intel® Microarchitecture Code Name Nehalem":

> — Integrated memory controller provides low-latency access to system memory and scalable memory bandwidth

So my understanding is that Xeon processors based on the Nehalem microarchitecture and newer microarchitectures all have an IMC. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Why does this matter? What programming problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @cody-gray Just for curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

While the statement quoted refers to Nehalem Xeons only, there is no reason to believe that Intel took or is going to take a step back in the technology of their server processors.

In fact sampling same datasheets from the net for the successive families of Xeon processors gives:

- [E5 family](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-e5-1600-2600-vol-1-datasheet.html) (Sandy Bridge)
- [E5-v2 family](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/xeon-e5-v2-datasheet-vol-1.pdf) (Ivy bridge)
- [E5-v3 family](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-e5-v3-datasheet-vol-1.html) (Haswell)
- [E5-v4 family](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/xeon-e5-v4-datasheet-vol-1.pdf) (Broadwell)
- [E3-v5 family](https://ark.intel.com/products/88176/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1240-v5-8M-Cache-3_50-GHz) (Xeon branding on Skylake-client) <sub><sup>Intel ark page, not datasheet</sup></sub>
- [Xeon Gold / Xeon Scalable Processors](https://ark.intel.com/products/120495/Intel-Xeon-Gold-6154-Processor-24_75M-Cache-3_00-GHz) (multi-socket capable Skylake-server)

Just by looking at the Table of Content it is easy to see that there is an iMC in each of those architecture.  Skylake-Server replaces the ring bus with a mesh, with multiple memory controllers on-die connected to the mesh.

There are other Xeon families (E7, E3), I haven't checked them all but they should just be different scaling of the E5 in terms of frequency, TDP, cache and cores.

Comment: Multi-socket Xeon (and Opteron) systems are [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access).  They have separate RAM slots for each socket, hooked up to the memory controllers on each physical chip.  (AFAIK, they still boot if you only put memory in the slots for one socket, and then it's not really NUMA (except for L3 cache behaviour), just one set of cores with a slower path to the one set of RAM.)